# setting full height to a component using % is not working

Tags: html, css

i have created a div component and added a few images inside that div.I have set a particular height(300px) to div & set the height of images inside it as 100%. It works fine in ios but in Android, the image is appearing on full screen instead of appearing only on that particular div.
What i need is, the image should fit to that div(occupy whole space of div).

My code;

```
<div style="height:300px;width:100%;">
<image src="lilly.png" style="height:100%;width:50%;float:right;">
<image src="rose.png" style="height:100%;width:50%;">
</div>
```

In HTML5 is there any other method to set elements height to occupy full space of div, instead of using 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as well:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/f00" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100/00f" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:0;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vAbRC/2/

Comment: The `font-size:0` is used to remove the spaces in the div, otherwise they become significant, and the blocks won't fit within 100% anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**css**

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[fsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vAbRC/)

hope this will work for you